# Servlet is not working and pages are not goes into tomcat webapps directory

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have create a simple servlet using Eclipse Luna IDE and a simple jsp page. When I deploy it, its not working. I am using tomcat 8.

Error is

HTTP Status 404 - /ServletLearning/DynamicPage/welcome
type: Status report

message: /ServletLearning/DynamicPage/welcome

description: The requested resource is not available.

[image: Directory structure of my project in Eclipse Luna IDE]

my code is here.

```
 package atulrai;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class DynamicServlet
*/
 @WebServlet("/DynamicServlet")
public class DynamicServlet extends HttpServlet {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    pw.println("Welcome " + name);
}
}
```

Jsp page is

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <title>dynamic page using Servlet</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form action="welcome" method="get">
    Enter your name:<input type="text" name="name"><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>ServletLearning</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>atulrai</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DynamicServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>atulrai</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is the Error your getting.? and i dont think you need to give @webservlet annotation when there is web.xml configured.

Comment: Error is

HTTP Status 404 - /ServletLearning/DynamicPage/welcome type: Status report

message: /ServletLearning/DynamicPage/welcome

description: The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change value of `action` attribute of `form` tag to

`<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome" method="get">`

also change `web.xml` to point to correct location.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>atulrai</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>atulrai.DynamicServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Either use `annotation` or `web.xml` to map servlet.